# *ngFor displaying data buy keep showing 'undefined' errors

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular

I have an *ngFor directive that is functioning and displaying data in my browser as expected. Although my console in chrome is showing 'undefined' errors.

classe :

```
export class Matchlist {

    matches?: (MatchesEntity)[] | null;
    endIndex: number;
    startIndex: number;
    totalGames: number;




}



  export class MatchesEntity {
    lane: string;
    gameId: number;
    champion: number;
    platformId: string;
    timestamp: number;
    queue: number;
    role: string;
    season: number;
    Matchinfo : Match;
  }


  export class Match {
    seasonId: number;
    queueId: number;
    gameId: number;
    participantIdentities?: (ParticipantIdentitiesEntity)[] | null;
    gameVersion: string;
    platformId: string;
    gameMode: string;
    mapId: number;
    gameType: string;
    teams?: (TeamsEntity)[] | null;
    participants?: (ParticipantsEntity)[] | null;
    gameDuration: number;
    gameCreation: number;
  }
  export class ParticipantIdentitiesEntity {
    player: Player;
    participantId: number;
  }
  export class Player {
    currentPlatformId: string;
    summonerName: string;
    matchHistoryUri: string;
    platformId: string;
    currentAccountId: string;
    profileIcon: number;
    summonerId: string;
    accountId: string;
  }
  export class TeamsEntity {
    firstDragon: boolean;
    bans?: (BansEntity)[] | null;
    firstInhibitor: boolean;
    win: string;
    firstRiftHerald: boolean;
    firstBaron: boolean;
    baronKills: number;
    riftHeraldKills: number;
    firstBlood: boolean;
    teamId: number;
    firstTower: boolean;
    vilemawKills: number;
    inhibitorKills: number;
    towerKills: number;
    dominionVictoryScore: number;
    dragonKills: number;
  }
  export class BansEntity {
    pickTurn: number;
    championId: number;
  }
  export class ParticipantsEntity {
    spell1Id: number;
    participantId: number;

    spell2Id: number;
    teamId: number;
    stats: Stats;
    championId: number;
  }

  export class Stats {
    neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle: number;
    visionScore: number;
    magicDamageDealtToChampions: number;
    largestMultiKill: number;
    totalTimeCrowdControlDealt: number;
    longestTimeSpentLiving: number;
    perk1Var1: number;
    perk1Var3: number;
    perk1Var2: number;
    tripleKills: number;
    perk5: number;
    perk4: number;
    playerScore9: number;
    playerScore8: number;
    kills: number;
    playerScore1: number;
    playerScore0: number;
    playerScore3: number;
    playerScore2: number;
    playerScore5: number;
    playerScore4: number;
    playerScore7: number;
    playerScore6: number;
    perk5Var1: number;
    perk5Var3: number;
    perk5Var2: number;
    totalScoreRank: number;
    neutralMinionsKilled: number;
    statPerk1: number;
    statPerk0: number;
    damageDealtToTurrets: number;
    physicalDamageDealtToChampions: number;
    damageDealtToObjectives: number;
    perk2Var2: number;
    perk2Var3: number;
    totalUnitsHealed: number;
    perk2Var1: number;
    perk4Var1: number;
    totalDamageTaken: number;
    perk4Var3: number;
    wardsKilled: number;
    largestCriticalStrike: number;
    largestKillingSpree: number;
    quadraKills: number;
    magicDamageDealt: number;
    firstBloodAssist: boolean;
    item2: number;
    item3: number;
    item0: number;
    item1: number;
    item6: number;
    item4: number;
    item5: number;
    perk1: number;
    perk0: number;
    perk3: number;
    perk2: number;
    perk3Var3: number;
    perk3Var2: number;
    perk3Var1: number;
    damageSelfMitigated: number;
    magicalDamageTaken: number;
    perk0Var2: number;
    firstInhibitorKill: boolean;
    trueDamageTaken: number;
    assists: number;
    perk4Var2: number;
    goldSpent: number;
    trueDamageDealt: number;
    participantId: number;
    physicalDamageDealt: number;
    sightWardsBoughtInGame: number;
    totalDamageDealtToChampions: number;
    physicalDamageTaken: number;
    totalPlayerScore: number;
    win: boolean;
    objectivePlayerScore: number;
    totalDamageDealt: number;
    neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle: number;
    deaths: number;
    wardsPlaced: number;
    perkPrimaryStyle: number;
    perkSubStyle: number;
    turretKills: number;
    firstBloodKill: boolean;
    trueDamageDealtToChampions: number;
    goldEarned: number;
    killingSprees: number;
    unrealKills: number;
    firstTowerAssist: boolean;
    firstTowerKill: boolean;
    champLevel: number;
    doubleKills: number;
    inhibitorKills: number;
    firstInhibitorAssist: boolean;
    perk0Var1: number;
    combatPlayerScore: number;
    perk0Var3: number;
    visionWardsBoughtInGame: number;
    pentaKills: number;
    totalHeal: number;
    totalMinionsKilled: number;
    timeCCingOthers: number;
    statPerk2: number;
  }
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, getDebugNode } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService } from './../../services/base.service';
import { LeagueService } from './../../services/league.service';
import { MatchlistService } from './../../services/matchlist.service';
import { MatchService } from './../../services/match.service';
import { Account } from 'src/app/models/accounts';
import { League } from 'src/app/models/league';
import { Matchlist } from 'src/app/models/matchlist';
import { Match } from 'src/app/models/match';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profil',
    templateUrl: './profil.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./profil.component.css']
})
export class ProfilComponent implements OnInit {
    account = <Account>{};
    leagues = <League[]>[];
    Matchlists = <Matchlist>{};
    Match = <Match>{};
    timeLeft: number = 60;
    accountid: string;

    constructor(private baseService: BaseService, private leagueService: LeagueService
        , private matchlistService: MatchlistService, private matchService: MatchService) {
        LeagueService

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.baseService.Getinfo("capman").subscribe((data: Account) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.account = data;
            this.accountid = data.accountId;
            this.leagueService.Getleaugue(data.id).subscribe((leauguedata: League[]) => {
                this.leagues = leauguedata;
                this.leagues = this.leagues.filter(item => item.queueType !== "RANKED_TFT" && item.queueType !== "RANKED_FLEX_TT");
                this.leagues = this.leagues.sort((b, a) => a.queueType.localeCompare(b.queueType));
                //    console.log("account id " + JSON.stringify(this.leagues) );
            })
            this.matchlistService.Getmatchlist(this.accountid, 0, 5).subscribe((Matchlistdata: Matchlist) => {
                console.log(Matchlistdata);
                this.Matchlists = Matchlistdata;
                this.Matchlists.matches.forEach(va => {
                    this.matchService.GetMatch(va.gameId).subscribe((Matchinfodata: Match) => {
                        va.Matchinfo = Matchinfodata;
                        console.log(this.accountid);
                    })
                });
            })
        })
    }
}
```

html :

```
<div class="match1" *ngFor="let arg of Matchlists.matches" style="margin-top: 40px;" >
    <div *ngFor="let part of arg.Matchinfo.participantIdentities">

            <div *ngIf="part.player.accountId == accountid">



        {{Matchlist.Matchinfo.participants[part.participantId-1].spell1Id  | summonerSpell     }}
        {{Matchlist.Matchinfo.participants[part.participantId-1].spell2Id   | summonerSpell        }}       
        {{Matchlist.Matchinfo.gameId       }}   
        {{Matchlist.Matchinfo.participants[part.participantId-1].championId | championname }}

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'participantIdentities' of undefined

enter code here

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots, I think it is better to include your code and errors in the question.

Comment: Post code instead of photos. And also attach the html code because the error is there. You ngFor is iterating the array before it get instanced / some variable is not yet populated when the firsts iterations start.

Comment: After posting code instead of images: please format your code properly.

Comment: The root of the problem is that you don't understand asynchrony, and the sequence of what happens. At t0, Angular instanciates your component. At t1, it calls ngOnInit. At t2, ngOnInit sends an HTTP request to get data, and subscribes to be notified when the data is available. At t3, Angular tries to render your component and fails, because the template tries displaying data that has not come back from the server yet. At t98543665, the response finally comes back from the server, the callback is called and the data is available to the template. Use ngIf to only display data that is available.

Comment: You can wrap the two ngFor in an <ng-container *ngIf=!!Matchlists && !!Matchlists.matches && !!Matchinfo && !!Matchinfo.participantIdentities">...</ng-container> to solve it quickly. But all the ts logic is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **ng-container** as a wrapper of your ngFor to avoid that

```
<ng-container *ngIf="arg.Matchinfo">
  <div *ngFor="let part of arg.Matchinfo.participantIdentities">
   ...
  </div>
<ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just use safe navigation operator `?.`

```
<div class="match1" *ngFor="let arg of Matchlists.matches" style="margin-top: 40px;" >
  <div *ngFor="let part of arg.Matchinfo?.participantIdentities"> 
      <div *ngIf="part.player.accountId == accountid">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[safe navigation operator ( ? ) and null property paths](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)